# How to change app folder name on Google Drive Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, backup, google-drive-android-api, drive

I have created app folder on Google Drive using [Storing Application Data](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) and [Google Drive Android API Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)

My app folder name is display as **"Text Editor"** as shown in below image.

[image]

How to change app folder name on Google Drive programmatically ?

Comment: 'Text Editor' is the name of your app (see [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it programmatically, but you can change it by editing the application name here: [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) by going to your project -> Enable API and get credentials like keys -> Enabled API(s) -> Drive API -> Drive UI integration. You can enter a description and upload icons as well.